# Wifi connected but no data transfer: “ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available”

Tags: 12.04, wireless, upgrade

I have upgraded from 10.04 to 12.04 using System Upgrade option. And since then, I am not able to use wireless. It ping for some 6 or 20 times and then throw this error:
"no Buffer space available".

I have seek online help and around as well. But nothing helped so far. I am not sure what is exactly missing.

Desperately expecting some reply.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/193264/wifi-connected-but-no-data-transfer-ping-sendmsg-no-buffer-space-available