# Schedule Shutdown returns an error: No buffer space available

Tags: shutdown, schedule

I have set up a few new headless Ubuntu servers.

```
:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

After a while they work, I try to schedule a restart but It returns error.

```
:~$ sudo shutdown -r 8
Failed to set wall message, ignoring:No buffer space available
Failed to call ScheduleShutdown in logind, no action will be taken: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

Sometimes, it works after a few tries. I checked `htop`, and `df -h` I couldn't see any problem.

I have enough space on the HDD

```
df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              6.3G  1.6M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  437G   89G  331G  22% /
tmpfs                               32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          2.0G  253M  1.6G  14% /boot
/dev/sda1                          1.1G  5.3M  1.1G   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                              6.3G  104K  6.3G   1% /run/user/0
tmpfs                              6.3G  4.0K  6.3G   1% /run/user/1000
```

and RAMs are used only %10 (128GB)

For a long time, I have not been resolving this problem. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Your provided details show you're well behind on applying security fixes; as a fully-upgraded 22.04 system will report itself as 22.04.3 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/02/24/ubuntu-22-04-2-lts-released/ shows the ISO release of 22.04.2, but installed systems upgraded to that in the week+ before the ISO release & you've not applied fixes to that level).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does “ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available” mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210451/what-does-ping-sendmsg-no-buffer-space-available-mean)